# why in a div inside another div is its top/bottom margin not behaving like its left/right one?

Tags: html, css

Why is the top/bottom margin of the inside div outside of the parent, but the left/right not?

```html
<body style="background-color: red">
  <div style="min-height: 2em; max-width:30em; background-color: black">
    <div style="background-color: white; margin:5em;">
      Where's the margin-top/bottom?
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

My expectation was that the inner div would have the `5 em` margin set in all directions.

Comment: And then try not to go mad when you use margins in percentages.

Comment: Use   float:left;    property in black div it will take margin you gave.

<body style="background-color: red">
  <div style="min-height: 2em; max-width:30em; background-color: black;float:left;">
    <div style="background-color: white; margin:5em;">
      Where's the margin-top/bottom?
    </div>
  </div>
</body>